# CUDA error: ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuCtxSynchronize()

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Every time I try to render my scene, I get this error:

CUDA error: ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuCtxSynchronize()

[image: CUDA error: ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuCtxSynchronize()]

I've tried messing around with my NVIDIA Control Panel (I have an NVIDIA GeForce 750M) and adding a TdrDelay in regedit after browsing through similar questions on the Blender StackExchange, but the problem persists.

I would try to allocate more video memory to Cycles if that's the problem, but I don't know how. (I do know I definitely have at least 1GB.)

I don't want to resort to rendering with only the CPU, or it would kill the purpose of having the NVIDIA card in the first place.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, ROBOTunderscore, it would be a good idea to share the ~.Blend file. [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) is preferred because the file will not be removed in a few months.

Comment: .blend has been added

Comment: Rendering on GPU you cannot change how much memory is allocated for rendering. You are limited to the amount of RAM built into the card.

Comment: The scene renders fine on my system (Nvidia 840M). I wonder if it is a bug particular to the 750's Kepler processor.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DHccW.png

Comment: As it turns out, this question shouldn't be on StackExchange, as it is something that had to be submitted to the Blender Bug Reporter, which I've done here: https://developer.blender.org/T45987. There are temporary solutions to this error on that page as well.

Comment: You didn't mention which nvidia driver you were using, or which OS. I get the same error on my GTX-960 (4gig VRAM), running in 64-bit Linux Mint, Blender 2.76 (64-bit) and the nvidia-352.63 driver and CUDA 7.5 for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: At the time of this post, I used Windows 10 64-bit and NVIDIA GeForce Windows 10 Driver 355.82. The card itself was NVIDIA GeForce 750M and I used Blender version 2.75a. At this time I technically found the solution, which is to completely disable Timeout Delay Recovery, but my computer doesnt let me disable it for some reason, so I just set the TdrDelay to "30000000000." I can't say how safe it is, so I haven't answered this question yet, but you can try it.